# Android: Overlay button onClick is rarely getting called

Tags: android, button, overlay

if i click on button then it moves 1,2 pixes (perform ontouch()) but not clicked (onclick()) ... but if i click accurately then it click but it is too hard to perform onclick() finctionality .... is there any way to perform onclick functionality easiy ... ontouch() functionalty is working fine.

```
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    overlayedButton = new Button(this);
    overlayedButton.setWidth(50);
    overlayedButton.setHeight(50);
    overlayedButton.setText("butn");
    overlayedButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    overlayedButton.setOnTouchListener(this);



    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(70, 70, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL|LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP ;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 0;
    wm.addView(overlayedButton, params);


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        overlayedButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appicon_icon_hovered);



        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();

        moving = false;

        int[] location = new int[2];
        overlayedButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        originalXPos = location[0];
        originalYPos = location[1];

        offsetX = originalXPos - x;
        offsetY = originalYPos - y;

    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        int[] topLeftLocationOnScreen = new int[2];
        topLeftView.getLocationOnScreen(topLeftLocationOnScreen);

        System.out.println("topLeftY="+topLeftLocationOnScreen[1]);
        System.out.println("originalY="+originalYPos);

        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();

        golparams = (LayoutParams) overlayedButton.getLayoutParams();

        int newX = (int) (offsetX + x);
        int newY = (int) (offsetY + y);

        if (Math.abs(newX - originalXPos) < 1 && Math.abs(newY - originalYPos) < 1 && !moving) {
        return false;
        }

        golparams.x = newX - (topLeftLocationOnScreen[0]);
        golparams.y = newY - (topLeftLocationOnScreen[1]);

        wm.updateViewLayout(overlayedButton, golparams);
        moving = true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        if (moving) {

            del=new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    try{

                        if(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                        {
                        del.sleep(2000);
                        }
//                      if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
//                      {
//                      del.sleep(2000);
//                      }
                }catch(InterruptedException e){}
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            overlayedButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appicon_icon);

                        }
                    });

                }
            });
            del.start();


        return true;
        }
        if(moving&&     originalXPos-event.getRawX()<5 ||originalYPos-event.getRawY()<5)
        {
            onClick(overlayedButton);
        }
    }

    return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        WindowManager wm1 = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        if(v==overlayedButton)
        {
    // do something

    }
```

Comment: Save the initial X and Y on ACTION_DOWM. O ACTION_UP compare them with the current X and Y. If they are outside the threshold you defined (50 should be good) then call onClick manually.

Comment: i try but nothng hapens, can u kindly further explain or write code ?